# Power Bi Embedded Deployment Features

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I am a software developer and have basic knowledge in `Power BI`.

I have following concerns in `Power BI Embedded` which is `PaaS`. Can you please have a look and let me know.

I know that using `powerBI Embedded`, we can embed power **BI reports** into any web application.I want to use azure `Sql DB` and `Power BI` embedded.

Questions:

1. Other than accessing the embedded power bi reports via my web
   application, do we have any other way where i can publish the power
   bi reports similar to SSRS report server?
2. As `app.powerbi.com` is `SaaS`, do we have any alternative
   deployment type for `PaaS` for deploying power bi reports which are
   embedded in web application?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the reports to [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) installed on your server on-premise, or in a Windows VM in the cloud, and then [embed them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed#:%7E:text=%20Embed%20a%20Power%20BI%20Report%20Server%20report,a%20SharePoint%20iFrame.%20Navigate%20to%20a...%20More%20) in your app. To [license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started#licensing-power-bi-report-server) this Power BI Report Server you either need to buy [Power BI Premium P SKU](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/), or to buy [SQL Server Enterprise with Software Assurance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019-pricing).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. As i want to use Power Bi Embedded feature only, do we have a feature of providing a report server url also (in cloud where reports are published) to the users where they can view the reports?

Comment: If you are providing the report URL to the user, then this report is not embedded. So I guess I do not understand your question.

Comment: Got your point. When I embed power bi reports in a web application, users are allowed to access power bi reports without having an individual license. Here we use Power BI APIs. Now my question is, is it possible to get a report server url also where users can access power bi published reports directly without having individual license?

Comment: The iframe source could be something like `http://username:password@server:port/Reports/powerbi/report1?rs:embed=true`, but I don't like this. The classic app owns data scenario with server side code for generating the access token and reports deployed to Power BI Service is way more secure.